# How can i use voice commands on Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: gnome-terminal, 21.04, voice-recognition

I need to install **voice command** for my laptop. But i don't know how.
As well as, **I am a beginner in Ubuntu**, and i don't know much about it.

I want to give commands to my laptop like: open some apps, take screenshot, etc.
**Can anybody help me to install voice command from scratch using terminal ?**.

Comment: Have you tried https://mycroft.ai/ ?

Comment: no but i will try it